# Jquery window height messed up

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, firefox, firebug

I'm using the jquery-rails 2.2.1 with the jquery 1.9.1
If i open the firebug and run the $(window).height() the height is 921.
If i close and open the firebug (same size) my $(window).height() changes to 1130
If i try to resize the firebug window i get those values

```
>>> $(window).height()
921
>>> $(window).height()
4276
>>> $(window).height()
6106
>>> $(window).height()
7326
```

My firefox is the 21.0 and the firebug 1.11.3.

I don't know what is happening i imagine the problem is the firebug, is this the correct way to get the window size (no the document)?
I'm using it to center a div in the middle of the screen

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   WSH = $(window).height();
   WSW = $(window).width();
   addSH = (WSH/2) - ($('#addSituation').height()/2);
   addSW = (WSW/2) - ($('#addSituation').width()/2);    
   $('#addSituation').animate({'margin-top': addSH}, 1000);
}
```

The first time i open the div its fine, if i open and close the firebug it messes, if i resize the firebug then it goes all the way down.
I updated the rails-jquery to the last version.
Is there a workaround?
Is there another way to do that?

Note: This div is in another file and i load it with the $(".myDiv").load().
The $(document).ready is inside this div.

I need to get the visible area height. so even if i mess with the "page" height it will be limited to my monitor size.
My resize event:

```
$("#layoutInside").css("min-height", ($("#showContent").height() > $("#menu").height() ? $("#showContent").height() : $("#menu").height()) + $(".footer").height() + 60)
```

The problem is the window height and the document height is the same.. 1008 the height is ok, but i want the area i can see in my monitor not the whole document area.

In pure JS it works

```
>>> window.innerHeight
502
>>> $(window).innerHeight()
1008
```

Regards.

Comment: No, its a div with a form. the size don't change.

Comment: but i want to animate, the problem is, the height messes up when i open/close the firebug, the size gets 7000px... my monitor is 1440x900

Comment: Pete, the animation is ok, but my $(window).height return 7000+/- pixels, so the margin-top is 7000 pixels.

Comment: The code you show will fire just once, when the document is ready. But since you log something on window resize, you must have added some code to the window.resize function. Show that code, because that is whats wrong

Comment: @HugoDelsing thanks, the code was wrong, it was another person that made it, so i did't checked it.
Regards.

Comment: I imagined the $(window).height was to get the visible frame height (is there a way to do that)?

Answer (score -2):

make sure to declare `<!DOCTYPE html>`   before anything else.
I was having the same issue and this worked for me.